# Bug width on Android browser with FB.init()

Tags: android, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I developp a mobile web app with facebook javascript SDK.

I use the meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>` to scale my content. But when I init my facebook app `FB.init()`, page width expands a lot and horizontal scroll appears.

How to fix this bug width on Android browser ? (don't appear on iOS)

Answer (score 2):

We were encountering this same issue and we came up with a workaround. Note that obviously this may be outdated in future FB API modifications.

We had to load in the FB SDK asyncronously and **make sure the XFBML param is set to false**.

```
<!-- this div element is required by FB JS SDK -->
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: facebookapikey, status: false, cookie: false, xfbml: false});
};
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Hope that helps everyone out.